# rspec-rails 2.14.2 with Rails 4.2 InvalidURIError

Tags: rspec2, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.2'` in my Gemfile.
After upgrading from Rails 4.1 to Rails 4.2 I've got the following error while running `rspec`:

```
Failure/Error: get 'api/...'
URI::InvalidURIError:
  the scheme http does not accept registry part: www.example.com:80api (or bad hostname?)
```

What's the fix?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding `/` to a path fixes the issue.

E.g.:
`get   'api/...'` => `get   '/api/...'`
`post  'api/...'` => `post  '/api/...'`
`patch 'api/...'` => `patch '/api/...'`
`put   'api/...'` => `put   '/api/...'`
etc.

**EDIT:** the reason is explained [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17870).